# Recursive SQL forum posts with replies to replies

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm really stuck here on finding a suitable way to pull all topic replies (and replies to replies) in SQL 2008.

Here is the DB structure.

**Forum_Cats**

```
catID    |    CatName
1        |    Q&A
2        |    General Discussion
```

**Forum_Topics**

```
topicID  |   catID   |   ReplyTo   |   TopicTitle                      
1        |   1       |   null      |   Just wondering if anyone knows?
2        |   1       |   1         |   Yeah I know that.
3        |   1       |   2         |   Thanks
```

So do I need a function where I can just pass a topicID and produce all reply children?

E.g. I pass the `topicID` of `1` and get back rows 2 and 3 as 2 is a reply of 1 and 3 is a reply for 2.

Comment: plz give your output for topic id 1 and 2

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement a recursive CTE.  Here's a great example for doing exactly what you want to do.

[Recursive Queries Using Common Table Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

If I have time and if you need help, I'll retrofit the example to fit your table structure, but it's pretty straight forward.  But I can easily see this going past the MAXRECURSION level.  A better approach might be to add a column to track the top level topic in each reply, then order by ReplyTo.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you take care to ensure the number of replies doesn't exceed the `MAXRECURSION` level, you can use a [CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx):

```
;WITH topic (topicId, catId, replyTo, topicTitle) AS (
    SELECT topicId, catId, replyTo, topicTitle
    FROM Forum_Topics F
    WHERE F.topicId = @topicId

    UNION ALL

    SELECT topicId, catId, replyTo, topicTitle
    FROM Forum_Topics F
    INNER JOIN topic T ON T.topicId = F.replyTo
)
SELECT * FROM topic
```

Comment: I get a returned dataset but each cell value is `<Unsupported Data Type>`

Comment: `doesn't exceed the MAXRECURSION level` - use option(maxrecursion 0) to turn off maxrecursion limit.